# how to apply the panel on button that is on one single page

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are three button and those have three panel now if i click on button one then show the panel one and if on second then second and same for third then what  may be the condition for that .?

Answer (score 0):

Could be easy with javascripts. The asp.net way can be:

Keep the buttons outside of the panels.

Mark the `EnableViewState` property to `true` for all the panels on aspx like:

```
<asp:Panel id="panel1" EnableViewstate = "true" runat="server">
...
</asp:Panel>
```

On `Page_Load` method, add this:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   panel1.Visible = false;
   panel2.Visible = false;
   panel3.Visible = false;
}
```

Now inside the button handlers, just change relevant panel's `Visible` property to `true` and others to `false` like:

```
protected void btn1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   panel1.Visible = true;
   panel2.Visible = false;
   panel3.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this.  For example, the code below will show panel1 if button1 is clicked, panel2 if button2 is clicked etc etc.  This is just a quick and dirty way to do accomplish what your asking.

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" AssociatedPanelClass="Panel1" Text="Button 1" class="btn" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" AssociatedPanelClass="Panel2" Text="Button 2" class="btn" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" AssociatedPanelClass="Panel3" Text="Button 3" class="btn" />

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" class="panel panel1 selected">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" >Panel 1</asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" class="panel panel2">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" >Panel 2</asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" class="panel panel3">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label" >Panel 3</asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showHide() {
            $(".panel").hide();//hide all panels
            $(".selected").show();//show the selected panel
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            showHide();//show the default panel
            $(".btn").click(function () {//assign a click handler to the buttons
                $(".selected").removeClass("selected");//remove class from previously selected panel
                switch ($(this).attr("AssociatedPanelClass")) {//assign new panel the selected class
                    case "Panel1":
                        $(".panel1").addClass("selected");
                        break;
                    case "Panel2":
                        $(".panel2").addClass("selected");
                        break;
                    case "Panel3":
                        $(".panel3").addClass("selected");
                        break;
                }
                showHide();//hide and display selected
                return false;//return false to avoid a postback
            });
        });
    </script>
```